# ImGui ColorPicker on ImU32

Tags: color-picker, imgui

The color picker in ImGui works on a float vector.

```
bool ColorPicker3(const char* label, float col[3], ImGuiColorEditFlags flags = 0);
```

But I have my color data stored in unsigned integers.

How can I have ColorPicker3 work on `ImU32` values instead?

Note that ImGUI is an immediate mode API, so it will change the values underneath you, which means conversion steps are not easily introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it?

```
bool ColorPicker3U32(const char* label, ImU32* color, ImGUIColorEditFlags flags = 0) {
   float col[3];
   col[0] = (float)((*color >>   ) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
   col[1] = (float)((*color >> 8 ) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
   col[2] = (float)((*color >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0f; 

   bool result = ColorPicker3(label, col, flags);

   *color = ((ImU32)(col[0] * 255.0f)      ) |
            ((ImU32)(col[1] * 255.0f) <<  8) |
            ((ImU32)(col[2] * 255.0f) << 16);

   return result;
}
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks. So yeah, I did not know that the value change actually happens in the ColorPicker3() calls. So conversions can be done just before and after it. I erroneously thought that values changed when you send the SDL events to IMGUI.